# boton javascript no abre modal (materialize)

Tags: javascript, modal, botón, materialize

estoy intentando crear una web app con app script y materialize. He creado un botón dentro de una tabla estática en html con clases materialize para darle estilo y abre una ventana modal.

```
<table class="striped responsive-table">
  <thead id="table-head">
    <tr>
    <th>N. RT</th>
    <th>Responsable</th>
    <th>Prioritat</th>
    <th>Ubicació</th>
    <th>Tipus d'incidència</th>
    <th>Descripció incidència</th>
    <th>Data</th>
    </tr>  
  </thead>
  <tbody id="table-body">
  <tr>
    <td>N. RT</td>
    <td>Responsable</td>
    <td>Prioritat</td>
    <td>Ubicació</td>
    <td>Tipus d'incidència</td>
    <td>Descripció incidència</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td><button id= "btn-editar" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-small btn modal-trigger" data-toggle ="modal" data-target="#editarTasca"><i class="material-icons right">edit</i>Editar</button></td>
    <td><button class="waves-effect waves-light btn-small" id="btn-eliminar-tasca"><i class="material-icons right">delete</i>Eliminar</button></td>
  </tr>
     
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Así funciona perfecto, abre la ventana modal sin problemas. Me interesa crear la tabla dinámica y acompañar a cada fila con un botón editar y otro eliminar.

Para crear los botones con los datos de la tabla utilizo el siguiente código:

```
function mostrarTareasPendientes(dataT){
 console.log(dataT);
  
  const tbody = document.getElementById("table-body");
  //Vaciamos la tabla antes de crearla
  tbody.innerHTML=" ";
  
  dataT.forEach(function(r){
  
  const row = document.createElement("tr");
  const col1 = document.createElement("td");
  col1.textContent = r[0];
  const col2 = document.createElement("td");
  col2.textContent = r[1];
  const col3 = document.createElement("td");
  col3.textContent = r[2];
  const col4 = document.createElement("td");
  col4.textContent = r[3];
  const col5 = document.createElement("td");
  col5.textContent = r[4];
  const col6 = document.createElement("td");
  col6.textContent = r[5];
  const col7 = document.createElement("td");
  col7.textContent = r[6];



const tdBotonE = document.createElement("td");
const botonEditar = document.createElement("button");
botonEditar.setAttribute = ("type","button");
botonEditar.className=("waves-effect waves-light btn-small btn modal-trigger");
botonEditar.setAttribute=("data-toggle" ,"modal")
botonEditar.setAttribute = ("data-target","#editarTasca");
botonEditar.textContent = "Editar  ";
const iEditar= document.createElement("span");
iEditar.className="material-icons right";
iEditar.innerHTML = "<span>edit</span>"; 


//Boton  Eliminar
const tdBotonB = document.createElement("td");
const botonEliminar = document.createElement("button");
botonEliminar.className="waves-effect waves-light btn-small red";
botonEliminar.textContent = "Eliminar  ";
const iEliminar= document.createElement("span");
iEliminar.className="material-icons right";
iEliminar.innerHTML = "<span>delete</span>"; 
botonEliminar.getElementById=("btn-eliminar-tasca");
botonEliminar.addEventListener("click",eliminarTareaAlerta);


  row.appendChild(col1);
  row.appendChild(col2);
  row.appendChild(col3);
  row.appendChild(col4);
  row.appendChild(col5);
  row.appendChild(col6);
  row.appendChild(col6);
  row.appendChild(col7);
 
  botonEditar.appendChild(iEditar);
  tdBotonE.appendChild(botonEditar);
  row.appendChild(tdBotonE);

  botonEliminar.appendChild(iEliminar);
  tdBotonB.appendChild(botonEliminar);
  row.appendChild(tdBotonB);

  tbody.appendChild(row);
 
  });
  
  }
```

Logro hacer funcionar el botón de eliminar que me lanza una alerta pero no el de editar. La consola me muestra el siguiente error:
materialize.min.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'M_Modal')
at HTMLBodyElement.value (materialize.min.js:6)
value @ materialize.min.js:6

Tengo inicializado materialize para este botón de la siguiente manera:

```
    // ventana modal
var mod = document.querySelectorAll('.waves-effect waves-light btn-small btn modal-trigger');
var instances = M.Modal.init(mod);
```

Pero aún así no me funciona.

Muchas gracias por vuestras respuestas.
Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

El problema que veo a simple vista es que en el boton editar no tienes ningún listener en cambio en el eliminar si, prueba a crear como tienes en el boton de eliminar `botonEliminar.addEventListener("click",eliminarTareaAlerta);` y dentro del método comprueba que te llega el valor que quieres.Un saludo

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu pronta respuesta finalmente lo resolví como me comentastes. Simplemente he creado la función //funcion que muestra el modal editar tareas
function editarTareas(){

const elem = document.getElementById('#editarTasca');
const instance = M.Modal.init(elem);
instance.open();
}

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente he resuelto el problema creando una función:

```
    //funcion que muestra el modal editar tareas
function editarTareas(){

const elem = document.getElementById('#editarTasca');
const instance = M.Modal.init(elem);
instance.open();
}
```

después desde el botón creado llamo a la función.

```
const tdBotonE = document.createElement("td");
const botonEditar = document.createElement("button");
botonEditar.setAttribute = ("type","button");
botonEditar.className=("waves-effect waves-light btn-small btn modal-trigger");
botonEditar.setAttribute=("data-toggle" ,"modal")
botonEditar.setAttribute = ("data-target","#editarTasca");
botonEditar.textContent = "Editar  ";
const iEditar= document.createElement("span");
iEditar.className="material-icons right";
iEditar.innerHTML = "<span>edit</span>"; 
botonEditar.getElementById=("btn-editar");
botonEditar.addEventListener("click", editarTareas);
```

Así logro que se abra la ventana modal.
Estoy aprendiendo, si alguien conoce otra forma más correcta de hacerlo agradecería su colaboración.
Un saludo,